# Force XCTest to use cached accessibility hierarchy view instead of doing new snapshot

Tags: ios, xcode, automated-tests, xctest

Is this possible to:

Force XCUITest to use cached accessibility hierarchy instead of making a new snapshot for it?

or maybe.. is there any way to control which XCTest actions (tap, swipe, etc) should make a new hierarchy snapshot before instead of using cached one?

I'm having some issues - I'm swiping through 20 pages in my app, they have a lot of elements and each swipe takes approx. 4 seconds, while 3 seconds are spent idle doing nothing on "Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for ..." step which is executed before `swipe` (automatically) and actually this is not needed at all in my cause because my selector for swipe doesn't change - it's always the same (and I'm not doing any assertions), so while I'm swiping I don't need to refresh hierarchy view, only at the end while I'm totally done swiping - and this is after 19 swipes.

Any suggestions?

I've tried to use EarlGrey in exactly the same screen and it has no issues, everything was really smooth, no delays between swipes. I bet it's getting hierarchy view too before each swipe (I'm not sure, or maybe the secret is that they're using cached hierarchy view in this case and that's why it's fast) but it seems that it takes a lot of less time and it's never noticeable like in XCUITest.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? The vast majority of my test runtime is spent in "Snapshot accessibility hierarchy"...

Comment: @hatfinch Sadly not. I went with EarlGrey "solution".